# how to send php mail one copy to admin and reply thanks message to subscriber?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have following php code for send mail, it works fine. it's contact form, the information send to admin and reply thanks message to subscriber.

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$sub=$_POST['subject'];
$describe=$_POST['describe'];
$mail -> From = "karthik@xfacttechnologies.com";
$mail -> FromName = "Vignesh Agency";
$mail -> AddAddress ("karthik@xfacttechnologies.com");
$mail -> headers = "From: vigneshagency\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$mail -> Subject = "Vignesh Agency";
$mail -> IsHTML (true);
$mail -> Body .= '<html><body>';
$mail -> Body .='<table style="width:60%;border:1px solid #eee;"      border="1" bordercolor="#eee" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">';
$mail -> Body .='<tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color:#7DA3B3;    color: white;"><h2>Customer Details</h2></th></tr>';
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Name </b></td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>E-mail </b></td><td>".$email."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Phone</b></td><td>".$phone."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Purpose </b></td><td>".$sub."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Message </b></td><td>".$describe."</td></tr> </table>";
$mail -> Body .= "</body></html>";


if(!$mail->Send()) 
echo "Error:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
else 
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://vigneshagency.com/contact.html'</script>";
exit();
```

Just send reply message to subscriber like "Thank you for visiting us"

Comment: What are you struggling with?

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: just i want to send another mail at the same time

Comment: So what's preventing you from doing so?

Comment: `mail($_POST['Email'], "Thanks for contacting us", $thanks_message,"From: PotterHandy.com <info@potterhandy.com>");`

Comment: I am not mean to be sarcastic, but is it hard for you to send 2 emails?

Comment: `mail($_POST['Email'], "Thanks for contacting us", $thanks_message,"From: PotterHandy.com <info@potterhandy.com>");` how to send like this message in mail

Comment: Your code already sends an email. Again, what's preventing your from sending another one using the same code as yours?

Comment: how to send reply mail

Comment: Reply in your own words or specified message? `if reply in your own words: use email; else: use the same method and send again.`

Comment: just i send auto reply email to subscriber

Answer (score 0):

Finally i find the solution.How to send Automated mail to Subscriber

```
$name=$_POST['name'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$sub=$_POST['subject'];
$describe=$_POST['describe'];
$mail -> From = "******@gmail.com";
$mail -> FromName = "abvdAgency";
$mail -> AddAddress ("******@gmail.com");
$mail -> headers = "From: abcd agency\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$mail -> headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$mail -> Subject = "abcd Agency";
$mail -> IsHTML (true);
$mail -> Body .= '<html><body>';
$mail -> Body .='<table style="width:60%;border:1px solid #eee;"      border="1" bordercolor="#eee" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0">';
$mail -> Body .='<tr><th colspan="2" style="background-color:#7DA3B3;    color: white;"><h2>Customer Details</h2></th></tr>';
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Name </b></td><td>".$name."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>E-mail </b></td><td>".$email."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Phone</b></td><td>".$phone."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Purpose </b></td><td>".$sub."</td></tr>";
$mail -> Body .="<tr><td><b>Message </b></td><td>".$describe."</td></tr> </table>";
$mail -> Body .= "</body></html>";


if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
echo "Error:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else 
{
// To send automated reply mail
$autoemail = new PHPMailer(); 
$autoemail->From = "*****@gmail.com"; 
$autoemail->FromName = "ABCD Agency"; 
$autoemail->AddAddress($email, $mail->FromName); 
$autoemail->Subject = "Autorepsonse: We received your submission"; 
$autoemail->Body = "We received your submission. We will contact you soon ...";
$autoemail->Send(); 
echo "<script>window.location = 'http://vigneshagency.com/contact.html'</script>";
exit();
}
```

Comment: You really should learn about the `header()` function instead of echoing `<script>window.location = 'http://www.foo.com/bar'; </script>`.

Comment: Well, use it instead of `echo`ing `javascript`.